# Autofill and password management for different servers using Ionic / Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I would like for an Ionic / Capacitor app that can connect to different servers to autofill and save the passwords for those servers.

It should work similar to how the Nextcloud app handles different servers. After choosing a server the user is prompted for the username and password. On Android you can click into the login field and the password manager can autofill that it remembered for the domain.

[image]

An Ionic app is similar to a browser window. Is it therefore only possible to get this behavior if the login form is rendered server-side?

Meaning that the app has to call the login-form by navigating to the server:

(App loads) -> (User chooses server) -> (App navigates to login form rendered by the server, e.g. `https://server.example.com/login`) -> (Browser now knows the URL and autofills the login) -> (JWT is returned and form redirects back to the app)

Or is there a way to emulate this behavior with Capacitor without compromising the users' security?

Comment: Nothing that is rendered in the browser can be considered "server-side": you might have a XHR call to different domains, each requiring its authentication, and then display data in the browser.

Comment: @Sébastien: Thanks for the comment. What I was trying to say is: Do I need to navigate to that server-side rendered URL so the browser loads the login on the correct URL? Otherwise the browser will just remember logins only for "localhost"?

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess you're correct and it is how it works, but I'm not 100% sure.